# jQuery selection performance comparison

Tags: jquery, performance

Is there a difference in performance between the two jQuery selections mentioned below?

```
jQuery('#someId')
```

versus

```
jQuery('span#someId')
```

Note: there is no space between "span" and "#someid"

Also, is there any purpose or advantage of mentioning the type of element like "span" before the ID?

Comment: I doubt there is a much of an advantage to mentioning the element prior to the ID, other than improving the readability of your code, i.e. if you have `$('span#new')` then someone knows the code is working with a `Span` element. If you search on Class then obviously there is a benefit of only finding the spans with a certain class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Althrough they should be the same, they are not. Putting only the `id` will alway be faster because jQuery first evaluate the string you pass to determine if it use javascript query selector or id selector. [Here the revelant jQuery code](https://gist.github.com/kagagnon/a13de27760ba1af883c0#file-gistfile1-js-L172).

That beign said, using only an id will always return 1 element while `span#id` will return every elements.

Check it out here : http://jsfiddle.net/ZW6Ed/

Of course using only the id is faster since `getElementById` scan the DOM and stop when it find the id while `querySelector` doesnt.

Why *"they should be the same, but they are not"*? Because having multiple id is not a valid HTML.

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery('#someId')` is eqvivalent to `jQuery('span#someId')`

As `id` is unique so better use `jQuery('#someId')`.

`id` always refers to unique element.

---

`jQuery('#someId')` -> element with id `someId`

`jQuery('span#someId')` -> Span element with id `someId`

---

[Performance Result - jsperf](http://jsperf.com/id-vs-span-id)

`jQuery('#someId')` is faster 
[image]

---

[Performance Test of Selectors - jsperf](http://jsperf.com/id-vs-span-id/3)
[image]

---

Comment: What a horrible jsperf - why would you perform IO and call `text()` if you wanted to measure selector performance?

Comment: @Esailija Can you please tell what should have been done to measure selector performance?

Comment: @TusharGupta just the selector e.g. `$("selector")`. After that it seems reasonable that the number of spans on the page affects results too, so you can vary those as well.